# Autofill for jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to fill a textbox with a value by default using the autofill function of jquery, this should disappear when the textbox is clicked. Any examples?

Comment: Ah, misread. SLaks suggestion sounds fine. HTML5 comes with the "placehold" attribute out of the box, btw.: http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_input_placeholder.asp

Comment: @polarblau : w3schools, yerk.

Comment: @ClemDesm: I think he'll get the point, despite the source. Helpful comment, on the other hand!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a watermark plugin, such as [this one](http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `placeholder` from html5 if you want but, by default, it'll be shown only in last version of : safari, chrome and the ff4 beta.

You can emulate it with [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/downloadjs/) which works well (I tested it)

See the docs [here](http://www.modernizr.com/docs/#input) .

Once loaded, you can use it like this :

```
<input type="text" name="foo" placeholder="Your name please" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onclick="if(this.value!='') this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value = 'Name:'" value="Name:" name="name" class="text">
```